# Aptana Studio 3 as plugin fails to startup

Tags: aptana

I have installed Eclipse 3.7.2 via PPA on Ubuntu 12.04 and subsequently I have clicked on Add New Software and the link to 64Bit Aptana studio 3.

It found the plugin and installed it correctly.

Now when I startup the Eclipse I get this error:

```
An internal error has occurred.
No more handlesNative code library failed to load. (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/xxx/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/plugins/com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.linux.x86_64_1.0.0.1295409059/os/linux/x86_64/libcefjni.so: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

**UPDATE:**

I wonder could it be because I am using jdk 7 from Oracle rather than Sun jdk 6 ?
This is the log file of Eclipse

```
!SESSION 2012-04-30 07:48:06.985 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0_04
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-04-30 07:48:07.951
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
        no swt-gtk in java.library.path
        Can't load library: /home/xxx/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so
        Can't load library: /home/xxx/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so

        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
```

Comment: With Eclipse 4.2 I had the same problem, but a very unhelpful GUI error message:

    Launching Aptana portal has encountered a problem: 
     java.lang.NullPointerException

Hopefully this will help others find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution:

The library **libjpeg62** is required otherwise the java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError shows up.

If using OpenJDK try this:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk libjpeg62 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 git-core
```

if using Oracle (sun) Java try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 git-core
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

[source](http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/)

Comment: I was also trying to fix this error on Eclipse Helios. But you saved my time. Thanks Kave :). Now it's working like charm :D after your solution.

Comment: @Neeraj, I am glad it helped you. :) Aptana Studio is a great app for web development

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete guide on how to install Aptana Studio 3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin). The same error you encountered is mentioned with the same solution. But might be helpful for people who want to do the full installation.

http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/